# Inference of user activity on binary condition variable

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution

I recently ran a test on our application that models a fairly contrived example:

Users are expected to add things to a bucket. We count the things in this bucket. A binary condition variable exists which could have an effect on the number of things users put things in a bucket.

The question I'm attempting to answer is if the variable has an effect on the number of things dropped in the bucket.

In statistical language:

*H0:* The binary variable has no effect on the # of things

*H-alt:* The binary variable increases the # of things in the bucket

**Question 1:**
What is the most appropriate statistical test to apply to infer if a difference exists in the counts?

I started with a student t test, but the assumption of normality and sample of continuous outcome variable is violated. The data are counts and I believe that the poisson distribution is the most appropriate. Chi square is tempting the data are not appropriate for a contingency table since each user drops 0 or more things in a bucket.

**Question 2:**

I think a general linear regression attempts to answer my question. Is my interpretation of the results correct?

```
group1 <- append(rep(0, 100), rpois(50, 110))
group2 <- append(rep(0, 100), rpois(50, 100))
df1 <- data.frame(cnt = group1,
                  gr  = TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(cnt = group2,
                  gr  = FALSE)
dat <- rbind(df1, df2)
fit <- glm(data=dat, cnt ~ gr, family='poisson')
summary(fit)
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  3.48493    0.01430 243.771  < 2e-16 ***
#grTRUE        0.11840    0.01964   6.027 1.67e-09 ***

fit$coefficients[[1]]

prTrue <- exp(fit$coefficients[[1]] + fit$coefficients[[2]] * 1)
(prTrue) / (1 + prTrue)  # => 0.9734889

prFalse <- exp(fit$coefficients[[1]] + fit$coefficients[[2]] * 0)
(prFalse) / (1 + prFalse) # => 0.9702558
```

Interpretation:

The sign of the grTrue coeffient is positive so the presence of the variable increases the number of things dropped in the bucket.

The presence of the variable increases the likelihood of increasing the # of things in the bucket by about 0.3% (0.973 - 0.970)

Thanks in advance. As you can tell, I'm kind of a noob at this and keep thinking myself in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @no0p_ @mjkirk for answering this for me on Twitter (link to conversation: https://twitter.com/brycemcd/status/613422042071834626)

The consensus opinion is to treat the groups as two populations and use the t distribution to test whether the populations are the same.

Continuing the example in the OP, the solution in R:

```
t.test(cnt ~ gr, data=dat)

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  cnt by gr
t = -0.48322, df = 296.16, p-value = 0.6293
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-14.068339   8.521672
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
       33.42667            36.20000
```

the t statistic is outside the acceptance level so we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the difference in the means is zero.